# Cookie properties with `document.cookie` vs `cookieStore.get`

Tags: javascript, cookies

If I set a cookie with certain properties using [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), they are reported back to me if I access the cookie with [`cookieStore.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CookieStore/get), but not with `document.cookie`:

```js
    document.cookie = ">>>Test123=Hello there; Secure; SameSite=Lax";
    console.log(document.cookie);
    cookieStore.get(">>>Test123").then(console.log);
```

`document.cookie` gives:

```
>>>Test123=Hello there
```

`cookieStore.get` gives:

```
{
  domain:null,
  expires:null,
  name:">>>Test123",
  path:"/834420",
  sameSite:"lax",
  secure:true,
  value:"Hello there"
}
```

Is there a way to get the information on, for instance, the `SameSite` property of a cookie without using `cookieStore`?

I've got the code here: https://playcode.io/834420/ if it helps

Comment: No, that is not possible. Reading `document.cookie` only returns `name=value` pairs, but no other information about how the cookie was originally set.

Comment: @CBroe thanks, very useful to know!